# Push Notifications on any change in Magento Database

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, magento-connect

I am providing Web-services of magento for POS Application.

I am Using Magento Soap-API for web-services.

How can I get last Updation in magento database??

If any changes occurs in magento database Then I(magento API) have to tell to POS so that POS can synchronize their local database with changes occurs in magento database.

Comment: Your question is likely much more broad than you intend. "any changes" would encompass me viewing a product page, as this would create entries in `log_*` and `report_*` tables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question likely depends on the processes driving updates to Magento.

A general answer would be to use Magento's event-observer system to register these changes with an update queue. Anything inserted via `save()` will trigger the generic [`model_save_after` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php#L465) event - while it won't catch everything, it might be of some use.

It might be entirely reasonable to use the above to build an index via CRON which will be efficient for Magento and for pushing to / being pulled by the POS.